# Powering capacitive soil moisture sensor from 5V Pin

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, sensor

I'm completely new to RPi, and I'd like to make a garden project, at first I would like to measure the soil moisture.

I purchased one of these sensors [https://www.amazon.com/Analog-Capacitive-Moisture-Corrosion-Resistant/dp/B07N11R8MD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N11R8MD) and also an ADS1015 ADC.

I followed the tutorial on this page, so I know my ADC is working properly https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-4-channel-adc-breakouts/python-circuitpython , after that I connected my sensor to the setup. VCC of the sensor is connected to the 3V3 of the RPi, GND to RPi GND, AOut to ADC A0.

In this case I don't get the right value since when it's dry i get 0 and when wet also 0 ( when i touch the sensor i get some value not 0).

After that i connected the vcc of the sensor to the 5V of the RPi. In this case I get right values as when dry 30000 when the sensor is in a glass of water it's 16000.

I read something about having to be careful with the 5V Pin, but I don't really understand if it's allowed to use the 5V Pin as a power source for the sensor?

My setup looks like this: https://banasiak.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/pepperbot2_bb3.png

My Code:

```
import board
import busio
import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1015 as ADS
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
from adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in import AnalogIn
ads = ADS.ADS1015(i2c)
chan0 = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0)
chan1 = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P1)
while True:

   print('Channel 0 is:',chan0.value, chan0.voltage)
   #print('Channel 1 is:',chan1.value, chan1.voltage)
   sleep(1)
```

Later on I would like to expand my project with more Soil moisture Sensor and a Relay controlling a pump.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: @shujaandi, Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah let me see. Your  moisture sensor EK1940 and ADC1015 ADC look good. (1) " Gikfun EK1940 - Capacitive moisture sensor V1.2 for 3V3/5V Rpi/Arduino operation) - $12 for two units":
https://www.amazon.com/Gikfun-Capacitive-Corrosion-Resistant-Detection/dp/B07H3P1NRM/ref=pd_rhf_dp_s_all_spx_wp_1_2/142-2601225-0649168?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07H3P1NRM&pd_rd_r=4deb6d31-cc8a-40f2-8926-89367d7d1070&pd_rd_w=FGFhV&pd_rd_wg=OVCMo&pf_rd_p=ffd394b3-6bb0-43ec-8bd8-b3dd44ab44d6&pf_rd_r=NKHGYQBM82CN5B467M84&psc=1&refRID=NKHGYQBM82CN5B467M84. / to continue, ...

Comment: The datasheet says that there is an on board 3V3/5V regulator and compatible for 5V Arduino and 3V3 Rpi. So I would recommend you to power the sensor with 3V3.

Comment: Some time ago I also played with moisture sensors, ADC 1015 and also relay KY019, and weight sensor HX711. You might like read the following forum discussion for more details: "Micro Green Project (moisture sensor, ADC, Relay, Weight Sensor) - rpi.org.forum 2019feb09
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=233311#p1427880. Cheers.

Comment: I also played with smart gardening, water pump, Hall effect water flow sensor, and solenoid valve etc. You can search the rpi.org.forum for more details. Have a great gardening project. Cheers.

Comment: Some more references on smart gardening: (1) Water pump, flow meter
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=231541&p=1418979&hilit=water+pump+tlfong01#p1418979

(2) Solenoid valve and relay
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=231541&p=1418979&hilit=water+pump+tlfong01#p1418278

(3) Solenoid valve
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=231541&p=1418979&hilit=water+pump+tlfong01#p1418054

(4) Water pump 1/2
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1341767&hilit=water+pump+tlfong01#p1341767

/ to continue, ...

Comment: (5) Water pump 2/2
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1377308&hilit=water+pump+tlfong01#p1377308. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the reccomendations @tlfong01, I will definitely check them. My problem with 3V3 is that my sensor shows 0 when it's in water and when it's completely dry, although when I connect with 5V pin it shows correct values.

Comment: As written in the specifications the output voltage of the sensor is between 0-3V so shouldn't damage the Pi, am I right?

Comment: Ah, I might have overlooked one point. The product sheet says the sensor is compatible with Arduino and Rpi,and that there is a 5V to 3V3 regulator on board. So if you power the sensor with 5V, the regulator with step down to 3V3 for the sensor chip which outputs signal 0V and around 3V to 3.2V. Now both Arduino and Rpi is happy with this 0V, 3V output signal. But if you power the sensor module with 3V3, the regulator might step down to 3V or even below to 2.8V. Then the sensor chip which expects to work with 3V3 will no longer work with 2.8V, and so won't give any sensible reading.

Comment: Yes, ***You are right***. 0~3V output would have 99% chance not damaging the Rpi. To confirm, you should power the sensor module with 5V. (I know there are smart regulators which step down from 5V to 3V3, and also from 3V3 to around 3V0, in this case (not your case) both 3V3 or 5V power should work. I confess I did not read the spec carefully, and might have given you the wrong advice. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and advices. Do you think that I should implement a logic level shifter just to avoid that 1% risk? Cheers

Comment: Well, if you have a long, say three year, learning and project plan, then I highly recommend to use 3V3 to 5V0 logic level conversion. Another important reason for using 5V logic is that if if you are using I2C/SPI, 5V logic has less noise problems, can entertain longer wiring. References: (1)  
Logical level converter 1/2
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=217340&p=1352588&hilit=uln2803+tlfong01#p1352588,
(2) Logical level converter
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=232411&p=1422940&hilit=uln2803+tlfong01#p1422940. Cheers.